# Data Binding from context menu inside a treeviewitem template

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command, contextmenu

i have tree view that has two levels, in the second level i have template with a context menu inside, and i'm trying to pass the TreeViewItem the ContextMenu belongs to as a CommandParameter, and so far no success, in my app the TreeviewItem has a HierarchicalDataTemplate but here is a simplified example for my XAML:

```
<Grid
    Background="Transparent">
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="blabla1"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="blabla2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="innerblalbla">
                <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Test" 
                                  Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.testCommand,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenuu}}}"
                                   CommandParameter=??????/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

and my viewModel(DataContext is set in code behind):

```
class myViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public myViewModel()
    {
        testCommand = new DelegateCommand(test);
    }

    public DelegateCommand testCommand { get; set; }

    private void test()
    {
        var x = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`MenuItem` doesn't lie in same Visual Tree as that of `TreeViewItem`**, that's why FindAncestor is not able to travel till Window.

You can use `PlacementTarget` of `ContextMenu` to get TreeViewItem which will inherit DataContext of window automatically.

This is how you do it:

```
<MenuItem Header="Test" 
          Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.testCommand,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                           AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
```